# Efficient decryption of AES/CFB8

Tags: haskell, encryption, cryptography, aes

I currently use this function to decrypt a data stream encrypted with AES in CFB8 mode:
https://github.com/Lazersmoke/civskell/blob/ebf4d761362ee42935faeeac0fe447abe96db0b5/src/Civskell/Tech/Encrypt.hs#L167-L175

```
cfb8Decrypt :: AES128 -> BS.ByteString -> BS.ByteString -> (BS.ByteString,BS.ByteString)
cfb8Decrypt c i = BS.foldl magic (BS.empty,i)
  where
    magic (ds,iv) d = (ds `BS.snoc` pt,ivFinal)
      where
        pt = BS.head (ecbEncrypt c iv) `xor` d
        -- snoc on cipher always
        ivFinal = BS.tail iv `BS.snoc` d
```

In case you don't understand Haskell, here's a quick rundown of how I believe this code works: (I did not write it)

- Given an IV and a list of encrypted bytes
- For every encrypted byte:

  - Encrypt the IV in ECB-mode.
  - Take the first byte of the encrypted IV and xor it with the encrypted byte. This is the next plaintext byte.
  - Remove the first byte from the IV
  - Append the encrypted byte to the IV
  - The next character will be decrypted using this new IV

Not that the ECB-mode encryption is handled by the cryptonite library. I could not find a library supporting CFB8.

Now, this works. However, with the amount of data I need to decrypt, it caps out one of my CPU cores and 80% of the time is just spent on decrypting.

The incoming data is not even that much, so this is not acceptable. Unfortunately, my knowledge of cryptography is rather limited and resources on CFB8 seem rather sparse. It appears that CFB8 is an uncommon mode of operation, also indicated by the lack of library support.

So, my question then is: How would I go about optimising this?

The incoming data is from a TCP stream, but the information is grouped into packets. The cfb8Decrypt function is called 2-5 times per packet, depending on the size. This is necessary, because the length of the packet is transmitted at the beginning, but the length of this size information is variable. After 1-4 decryptions are used to decrypt the length, the entire packet will be decrypted at once. I thought about trying to reduce this, but I am unsure if it would have any effect on speed at all.

Edit: Profiling results: http://svgur.com/i/40b.svg

Comment: "How would I go about optimising this?" - begin by [profiling](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html) your program.

Comment: I mean... that is how I know 80% of time is spent on decryption. What exactly do you want me to look for?

Comment: You should profile `cfb8Decrypt` itself (unless you mean that 80% of the time spent inside `cfb8Decrypt` is spent on `ecbEncrypt`, in which case there probably isn't much you can do except replacing `ecbEncrypt` with a faster version). But you are using `snoc` inside a `fold` so your program has at least quadratic complexity (and presumably you call it on sizeable chunks of data, or performance wouldn't be an issue at all). Perhaps look at [Builder](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Builder.html).

Comment: Yeah, a good chunk of time is actually spent in ecbEncrypt. I was hoping there was a more efficient way of doing this than calling ecbEncrypt for every character. Using a Builder is a good shout, though, since there is some time to be gained in cfb8Decrypt itself and the snoc might be it. I'll add the profiling results to the question.

Comment: Indeed, your profiling shows that `ecbEncrypt` is the majour issue. It also shows that within the call to `ecbEncrypt` most of the time is spent doing foreign marshalling (`allocAndFreeze`); based on this, it is very likely that finding a way to call `ecbEncrypt` fewer times would speed this up considerably. However, I don't know much about cryptography or this algorithm, so I can't recommend any way to do so. Perhaps consider crossposting this to the CS or crypto stack exchanges (they may be able to recommend a better algorithm).

Comment: Also consider writing your function in C (using the appropriate C functions to replace `ecbEncrypt` which you could find e.g. [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.24/src/cbits/cryptonite_aes.c)) and then calling it once per packet from Haskell. This would reduce the amount of marshalling done considerably. It probably isn't very satisfactory have to write your Haskell code in C, but often if you want to squeeze out every bit of performance possible, that's what you must do.

Comment: Does your computer have aesni?

Comment: @user2407038 Thank you very much for that, I did not previously realise that it was mostly marshalling causing this issue. I'll try to rewrite it in C, although I don't have much experience interfacing with C (I do actually have some, though! :D) In the meantime, you may want to consider formulating this into an actual answer. You deserve an upvote and possibly an accept (if I can solve it this way, that is :P)

Comment: Hey! My answer already has AES-NI! And the marshalling bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFB8 was created to have good error propagation properties over a noisy channel. It is well known that it is not fast; it is actually 16 times as slow, as it requires a block encrypt for each byte. Currently it is not very hot, as we tend to use CRC's for the data layer and MAC for integrity on cryptographic levels against willful attacks.

How can you speed it up? The only thing you can really do is to use a fast library. The library you are currently using seems to have support for AES-NI, so make sure that is enabled on your CPU and BIOS.

However, it is very likely that it won't speed up much if you have to call it block for block. You really want to use a native call that takes the whole packet and decrypts it. AES-NI in it's slowest on an Atom implementing TLS still goes to 20 MiB/s, but on server chips AES-NI often goes far beyond the 1 GiB/s limits. Assembly or optimized C should be about 6/7 times as slow when AES-NI is not available.

Functional programming languages like Haskell are not really created for fast I/O nor fast bit-operations. So you can bet that it will be much, much slower than e.g. Java or C#, and those are already much slower than native code let alone assembly code or specialized instructions.

Memory nowadays is pretty fast; CPU's are however much much faster. So avoiding spurious memory allocations and copying should be avoided (again, not that easy to do on a fully functional language, all the more reason to do as much as possible in native code). Do however make sure that there are no buffer overflow issues or you will have fast AES/CFB within an insecure application.